# Grep specific lines when numbered words are involved

Tags: grep

I have a file with the following structure.

```
name #chrom chromStart chromEnd encodeLabel description
EH38E1310153 chr1 181251 181601 pELS EH38E1310153
EH38E1310154 chr2 190865 191071 dELS EH38E1310154
EH38E1310158 chr3 778562 778912 PLS EH38E1310158
EH38E1310159 chr4 779086 779355 PLS EH38E1310159
EH38E1310160 chr8 779727 780060 pELS EH38E1310160
EH38E1310162 chr17 790397 790626 CTCF-only EH38E1310162
EH38E1310164 chr18 807736 807916 dELS EH38E1310164
EH38E1310165 chr19 812113 812266 dELS EH38E1310165
```

I need the lines with `chr1` and that only. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
grep 'chr1' filename.txt > Output.txt
```

This pulls out the following lines:

```
EH38E1310153 chr1 181251 181601 pELS EH38E1310153
EH38E1310162 chr17 790397 790626 CTCF-only EH38E1310162
EH38E1310164 chr18 807736 807916 dELS EH38E1310164
EH38E1310165 chr19 812113 812266 dELS EH38E1310165
```

It seems like the default grep search is greedy, when I need it to be specific. I do not need `chr1*`.
I tried the `-o` flag, but this simply returned `chr1`. I need the whole line.

How can I solve this?

Comment: *grep -w chr1 filename.txt*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `grep '\<chr1\>' filename.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, could you explain the syntax? I have never come across `\<text\>` with grep before

Comment: Systems with GNU grep (e.g., most Linux systems) can use `grep -w` as a shorthand for this in most cases.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer those `\<...\>` word boundaries are already GNU-specific so if they have  that then then have `-w`.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` isn't "greedy". It just looks for the given pattern on the line, and prints the whole line if that pattern is found *anywhere* on the line. Or, if `-o` is given, it just prints the matching part.

All the lines you show, contain the string `chr1`. In one of them it's immediately followed by a space, and in three, it's immediately followed by something else. But that doesn't matter, it's still that string on each line.

If you want to check if the second field on the line is exactly the given string, use a tool like awk that can handle such field-based text input.

E.g.

```
awk -v value=chr1 '$2 == value' < filename.txt > Output.txt
```